# Steam refuses to launch on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: games, steam

I'm using an Ubuntu Acer laptop, and I installed steam about two months ago, having no problems whatsoever. Now, when I try to launch steam, nothing happens. Even the desktop icons for my games are not launching. No notification shows up or anything, so I have no idea what is going on. I tried updating my software and re-installing steam, yet nothing. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: It may be updating in the background.  You could `ps -ef | grep -i steam` and check.  Or launch it from a terminal and see if it produces any output.  Also, re-installing doesn't do much for steam, it installs a bunch of stuff to your home directory on first and successive run.  You'd have to remove those files to really re-install.